Go: "invalid GOSUMDB: malformed verifier id" error during tool installation
I'm trying to install Go tools using the built-in "Go: Install/Update Tools" command in VS Code, but I'm encountering an error for several tools. The error message is:
verifying module: invalid GOSUMDB: malformed verifier id

Details:

Go version: go1.22.5
Operating System: macOS
Architecture: amd64
Specific tools with the error: all the 7 tools (gopls, gotest, gomodifytags, impl, goplay, dlv, staticcheck)

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

I've restarted VS Code.
I've reinstalled go (from https://go.dev/doc/install)
I've reinstalled vscode go extention
deleted go mod cache (go clean -modcache)

Question:

What could be causing this "invalid GOSUMDB: malformed verifier id"
error within VS Code's "Go: Install/Update Tools"?
Are there specific solutions I can try to resolve this and successfully install the Go tools?


If you are in a trusted environment and need a quick workaround, you can disable the checksum database by setting GOSUMDB to off. However, this is not recommended for production environments as it disables integrity verification.
go env -w GOSUMDB='off'

@zangw in this case I got download go1.22.5: golang.org/toolchain@v0.0.1-go1.22.5.windows-amd64: verifying module: checksum database disabled by GOSUMDB=off

@vyacheslav.kislov, you may try go clean -modcache

@zangw thanks, but did not help. Then I installed 1.22.5 using installer and now all works fine
